# Java Observer Pattern - Pass info to other class - methods

Tags: java, observer-pattern, observers

Query - I would like to know how I should proceed to code if I need to make the information in the Observer class available to methods in other classes.

The observer receives the updates from Observable in the form of Object[]. I am able to print the output onto console, but not clear on how to make this information available to other classes.

I tried by creating a getInfo method in the Observer which returns the Object[] & then instantiating the Observer in the class where I need the info, calling the getInfo method. But I am getting a null pointer exception.

**Code - Observer**

```
private String car;
private CarModel carModel;

public broadcastObserver(Observable observable){
    observable.addObserver(this);
}

@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object arg) {
    Object[] subjectMessage = (Object[])arg;
int i = 0;
    for (Object o : subjectMessage) {
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                car = (String)o;
                i++;
                break;
            case 1:
                carModel = (CarModel) o;
                i++;
                break;
        }
    }
}
public Object[] getObserverFeed(){
    Object[] observerFeed = new Object[]{car,carModel};
    return observerFeed;
}
```

**Code - Class Method where info is needed**

```
broadcastObserver bO = new broadcastObserver();

Object[] feed = bO.getObserverFeed();
```

Comment: Please post your code instead of telling a story about that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert the flow of data: instead of trying to *pull* info from the observer with get-methods, use the observer to *push* it to where it's needed.

Comment: thanks, can you point me in the direction on how to achieve that. I did quite a bit of searching on that, but so far unable to figure out. Apologies am quite new to this.

Comment: Essentially: whatever you want to do with `bO.getObserverFeed()`, move it to the `update` method.